# How do I get the columns that a statsmodels / patsy formula depends on?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

Suppose I have a `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'x2': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6], 
                   'x3': [.1, .1, .2, 4, 8], 
                   'y': [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]})
```

Now I fit a `statsmodels` model using a formula (which uses `patsy` under the hood):

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
fit = smf.ols(formula='y ~ x1:x2', data=df).fit()
```

What I want is a list of the columns of `df` that `fit` depends on, so that I can use `fit.predict()` on another dataset. If I try `list(fit.params.index)`, for example, I get:

```
['Intercept', 'x1:x2']
```

I've tried recreating the patsy design matrix, and using `design_info`, but I still only ever get `x1:x2`. What I want is:

```
['x1', 'x2']
```

Or even:

```
['Intercept', 'x1', 'x2']
```

How can I get this from just the `fit` object?

Comment: Why not just split `'x1:x2'` on `':'`, then, if you're just interacting `x1` and `x2`? Something like `fit.model.formula.split(':')` and then filter the rest out appropriately. Hell, a regex split would be even better, handling `+`, `:`, etc.

Comment: @bwk have you made any progress with this issue? Have a look at my answer, it should fit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply test if the column names appear in the string representation of the formula:

```
ols = smf.ols(formula='y ~ x1:x2', data=df)
fit = ols.fit()

print([c for c in df.columns if c in ols.formula])
['x1', 'x2', 'y']
```

There is another approach by reconstructing the patsy model (more verbose, but also more reliable) and it does not depend on the original data frame:

```
md = patsy.ModelDesc.from_formula(ols.formula)
termlist = md.rhs_termlist + md.lhs_termlist

factors = []
for term in termlist:
    for factor in term.factors:
        factors.append(factor.name())

print(factors)
['x1', 'x2', 'y']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: This doesn't work if you happen to have a column name that is a substring of the formula. For example, I have a column called `rt`, which gets captured by the formula `C(other_col, Helmert)`

Comment: @sammosummo Indeed, the first approach I mention in the answer will match any substrings. However, the second approach does not perform this string matching.

Comment: The second approach doesn't answer the OP's question, since it finds patsy terms, not the columns from the original dataframe. These aren't the same when using categorically coded factors.

Answer (score 2):

`predict` takes the same structure of data frame or a dictionary, and a call patsy converts it in a compatible way. To replicate this you can also check the code in `statsmodels.base.model.Results.predict` the core of which is

```
exog = dmatrix(self.model.data.design_info.builder,
                           exog, return_type="dataframe")
```

The formula information itself is stored in the description of the `terms` in `design_info`. The variable names itself are used in `summary()` and as index in the returned pandas Series for example in `results.params`.

Comment: Getting the formula is not a problem. The variable names in `summary()` are not the original variables in the DataFrame, but the _transformed_ variable names; i.e. there's "x1:x2" instead of "x1" and "x2" separately.

Answer (score 0):

`ols.exog_names` and `ols.endog_names` should do it